# How does the digital compass "figure of eight" waving for calibration work?

Tags: iphone, compass

What is the logic behind the "wave your device in a figure of eight to calibrate the compass"? How does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for moving your device in a figure eight is to help it calibrate itself against magnetic interference. By moving it slightly its able to detect the differences and return a more accurate reading.

You can read the Apple knowledge base article [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2767)